# Problem parsing Javascript containing backtick with js2xml

Tags: javascript, python, js2xml

I'm using Python/js2xml to parse JavaScript from a webpage but I'm getting an error message due to the inclusion of backticks in the JavaScript for example...

```
htmlBlock = `<option disabled selected value="0">Select lesson...</option>`;
```

...is raising the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\course_to_course_pkl.py", line 71, in <module>
    course_admin_parsed = js2xml.parse(course_admin_js) # js_course_structure.txt
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\js2xml\__init__.py", line 17, in parse
    tree = _parser.parse(text, debug=debug)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\calmjs\parse\parsers\es5.py", line 115, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ply\yacc.py", line 331, in parse
    return self.parseopt(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ply\yacc.py", line 757, in parseopt
    lookahead = get_token()     # Get the next token
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\calmjs\parse\lexers\es5.py", line 290, in _token
    tok = self._get_update_token()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\calmjs\parse\lexers\es5.py", line 355, in _get_update_token
    self._set_tokens(self.get_lexer_token())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\calmjs\parse\lexers\es5.py", line 242, in get_lexer_token
    token = self.lexer.token()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ply\lex.py", line 386, in token
    newtok = self.lexerrorf(tok)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\calmjs\parse\lexers\es5.py", line 687, in t_error
    raise ECMASyntaxError(
calmjs.parse.exceptions.ECMASyntaxError: Illegal character '`' at 1299:23 after '=' at 1299:21
```

I can't seem to find a solution - I've tried looking through the calmjs package to see if I can simply add the backtick in the list of recognised characters but it's beyond me.

Comment: Do you mean [this *js2xml*](https://pypi.org/project/js2xml/)? According to [this 2020 update](https://github.com/scrapinghub/js2xml#v040-2020-06-04), it uses [*calmjs.parse*](https://github.com/calmjs/calmjs.parse) under the hood, which [only supports ES5](https://github.com/calmjs/calmjs.parse#usage).

Comment: Yes - the parser is calmjs.parse

Comment: You probably need a better parser then.

Comment: Can you suggest one please?

Comment: I don't know of any. Besides, questions seeking for recommendations are off-topic for SO. Check out our sister site [softwarerecs.se] instead.

Comment: A quick search gives me [esprisma](//pypi.org/project/esprima/), which supports up to ES2017. Note that this just parses the JavaScript, it doesn't turn it into XML. As an alternative you could also transpile your JavaScript to an older version with [Babel](//babeljs.io/), then run the result through js2xml.

Answer (score 0):

As `@InSync` mentioned in the comment, The error comes from `calmjs.parse` method which only supports `ES5`. But **Template Literals** is an `ES6` feature.

https://github.com/calmjs/calmjs.parse

You have to replace `backticks` with `double` or `single quote`.

```js
htmlBlock = "<option disabled selected value=\"0\">Select lesson...</option>";
```

Comment: OK - thank you @InSync - so I'll need to escape all existing double quotation marks within the template literal and then replace the template literal with double quotation marks?

Comment: This will work so long as the quoted string does not include value interpolation expressions.

Comment: I didn't write the script so I'm not sure :) I'll give it a go.

Comment: Then try something better instead of `js2xml`. As **3limin4t0r**, The https://pypi.org/project/esprima/ seems a good one.